# Binary search tree crashes unexpectedly on valid input

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

The program should make basic operations in a binary search tree, such as searching for items, adding new elements, etc... However, it often crashes, even on valid input.

```
/* Edit: Translated the symbols from Portuguese into
 * English for readibility's sake. Please base any
 * answers upon the original post, as I could have made
 * something wrong in the process. I translated string
 * literals, too, and that may cause input to the original
 * program to become invalid. Again, read the original post.
 *  - KemyLand
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXP 40
#define MAXT 100

typedef enum
{
    false,
    true
} bool;

struct node
{
    char *word, *translation;
    bool marker;
    struct node *leftChild;
    struct node *rightChild;
};

void loader(char *word, char *translation);
void add(char *word, char *translation);
void mark(char *word);
void alphanum_list();
void mark_list();
struct node *root = NULL;
struct node* search(char *word);
struct node* load();


int main()
{
    char word[MAXP];
    char translation[MAXT];
    char option[15];

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s", option);
        printf("%s", option);

        if(strcmp(option, "LOAD") == 0) {
            load();
        } else if(strcmp(option, "ADD") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", word);
            scanf("%s", translation);
            load(word, translation);
        } else if(strcmp(option, "SEARCH") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", word);
            search(word);
        } else if(strcmp(option, "MARK") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", word);
            mark(word);
        } else if(strcmp(option, "ALPHANUM_LIST") == 0) {
            alphanum_list();
        } else if(strcmp(option, "MARK_LIST") == 0) {
            mark_list();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

struct node* search(char *word)
{
    struct node *current=root;

    while(strcmp(current->word, word) != 0) {
        if(current != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(current->word,word) < 0) {
                current = current->leftChild;
            } else {
                current = current->rightChild;
            }

            if(current == NULL) {
                printf("WORD DOESN'T EXIST\n");
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", current->word, current->translation);
    return current;
}
```

Should load input tree.

```
struct node* load()
{
    char str[1000];
    char word[MAXP];
    char translation[MAXT];

    while(1) {
        do {
            gets(str);
            sscanf("%s %s", word, translation);
            loader(word, translation);
        } while(strcmp(str,"end$dictionary") != 0);
        printf("DICTIONARY LOADED\n");
    }
}
```

The operations with the tree are defined here.

```
void loader(char *word, char *translation)
{
    struct node *tempNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current;
    struct node *father;

    tempNode->word = word;
    tempNode->translation = translation;
    tempNode->leftChild = NULL;
    tempNode->rightChild = NULL;

    /* If tree is empty */
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = tempNode;
    } else {
        current = root;
        father = NULL;
    }

    while(1) {
        father = current;

        /* Goes to the left side of the tree */
        if(strcmp(word,father->word) < 0) {
            current = current->leftChild;
            /* Insert to the left */

            if(current == NULL) {
                father->leftChild = tempNode;
                return;
            }
        } else {
            current = current->rightChild;

            if(current == NULL) {
                father->rightChild = tempNode;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void add(char *word, char *translation)
{
    struct node *tempNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current;
    struct node *father;

    tempNode->word = word;
    tempNode->translation = translation;
    tempNode->leftChild = NULL;
    tempNode->rightChild = NULL;

    /* If tree is empty */
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = tempNode;
    } else {
        current = root;
        father = NULL;
    }

    while(1) {
        father = current;

        /* Goes to the left side of the three */
        if(strcmp(word,father->word) < 0) {
            current = current->leftChild;
            /* Insert to the left */

            if(current == NULL) {
                father->leftChild = tempNode;
                printf("WORD ADDED\n");
                return;
            } else {
                printf("WORD ALREADY EXISTS\n");
            }
        } else {
            current = current->rightChild;

            if(current == NULL) {
                father->rightChild = tempNode;
                printf("WORD ADDED\n");
                return;
            } else {
                printf("WORD ALREADY EXISTS\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

void mark(char *word)
{
    struct node *tempWord = search(word);

    if(tempWord != NULL) {
        tempWord->marker = true;
        printf("%s MARKED\n", tempWord->word);
    } else {
        printf("WORD NOT FOUND\n");
    }
}

void alphanum_list()
{
    struct node *tempNode = root;
    if(tempNode != NULL) {
        alphanum_list(tempNode->leftChild);
        printf("%s\n", tempNode->word);
        alphanum_list(tempNode->rightChild);
    }

    printf("END OF LIST\n");
}

void mark_list()
{
    struct node *tempNode = root;
    if(tempNode != NULL) {
        mark_list(tempNode->leftChild);
        if(tempNode->marker == true) {
            printf("%s\n", tempNode->word);
        }

        mark_list(tempNode->rightChild);
    }

    printf("END OF MARKED ENTRIES\n");
}
```

Comment: Do you care if I translate your code's symbol names from Portuguese into English, so for others to read it more easily?

Comment: No, there's no problem.

Comment: What 'input'? When you ran/stepped it under your debugger, which line caused the 'crash' and what were the relevant var values?  What does 'crash' mean?  What error-message/s were issued?  If none, is the thread blocked or looping?  Sorry, but you have provided next-to no useful information that might help with narrowing down the problem/s:(

Comment: I build the program using CodeBlocks and the program as no compile errors nor warnings. It is supposed that the program run in a plataform that provides the input to build the BST, that's why the function "carrega", that loads that input and builds a BST. It should work like a dictionary, palavra stands for word and traducao for translation

Comment: BTW, edited everything with symbols translated. Too hard for everyone to understand the code otherwise.

Comment: On another note, you should post *an actual question* (a `Sentence of this form?`), and show your debugging efforts. Otherwise, this will get downvoted/close pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's actually the first time I'm using this website, so I'm not aware of how it all works

Comment: @ZéPedro: [The guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should get you started without problems.

Comment: Can't u find the problem in my code??

Comment: @ZéPedro: Yes, of course I can, but the question is not appropriate. It needs to be so in order to be answered.

Comment: How do u want me to make the question? I did provide all the information I can

Comment: I think your misunderstanding how this works. When you come to StackOverflow, you come with a *proper problem*, that is, a question whose answer you lack. We can then colaborate in order to find the solution. However, we're not here in order to find *both* the problem and the solution. You should find the problem yourself. That is, you know that the program crashes, right? That's a consecuence of the problem, but not the problem itself. Now, try to relate that to a question. You don't need to have the answer, but once you have the question, you're welcome here.

Comment: I got it now. I thought I provided every information necessary.

Comment: Yet another `do / while` failure: the end of dictionary marker `end$dictionary` **is** inserted into the dictionary!

Comment: the function `gets()` is long since depreciated and completely removed in the latest C standard.  Suggest replacing with `fgets()`

Comment: the prototypes for functions that do not take any parameters should have the word `void` between the parens, other wise the compiler thinks there may be parameters and they just were not specified.

Comment: rather than trying cobble together definitions for `false` and `true` and `bool`  use the statement `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers (i.e. 15)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` or `#define` statements to give 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: in C, the returned type from memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*`.  The returned type can be assigned to any other pointer.   Casting just clutters the code, leads to bugs when maintaining the code, and makes the code more difficult to understand and debug.  Suggest removing the cast of the returned value from calls to the memory allocation functions

Comment: comparing to `true` is always a bad idea, (comparing to `!false` is passable but why bother,  just say something like: `if( tempNode )` or `if(tempNode->marker )`  and if checking for `false` just say `if( !tempNode )`

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `scanf("%s", word);`,  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful  2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always place a max length modifier (that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer) so the user cannot overrun the input buffer.  Otherwise undefined behaviour will result, which can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, the '%s' format specifier will not input past any `white space`.  To get around that problem, the format string should contain a leading space.

Comment: this line: `load(word, translation);` is not correct as the 'load()` function is not expecting any parameters perhaps you meant `loader()` which is expecting the two parameters

Comment: the `load()` function contains no way to exit the while loop!.  suggest eliminating the outer `while()` loop.

Comment: the function:`alphanum_list()` is being called, sometimes with no parameters and recursively with a parameter.  This will not work, especially as no provision is in the function to handle any parameter

Comment: the function: `mark_list` is defined as having no parameters, but is called recursively with a parameter.  This will not work, especially as no provision is in the function to handle any parameter.

Comment: the `load()` function signature says that it will return a `struct node*` but no such return statement exists in the function

Comment: the main function fails to handle the case where the user enters some unexpected value. Given the amount of typing the user must perform in the main() function and the fact that the user is left to guess as what they should enter, strongly suggest implementing a 'menu' so the user only has to enter a 'key' char from the menu rather than typing in some string. Also that would make checking the input a simple switch() and case` construct.

Comment: the `load()` function probably should check for the exit string: `"end$dictionary"` before calling  'loader()` rather than after calling `loader()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loader` function does not duplicate the words inserted in the dictionary nodes... they will all point to the local arrays in the `load` function, that will become invalid as soon as the `load` function returns. Fix the code this way:

```
tempNode->word = strdup(word);
tempNode->translation = strdup(translation);
tempNode->leftChild = NULL;
tempNode->rightChild = NULL;
```

When the dictionary is empty, you store the new node to `root`, but you should then return from the function. The current code then invokes undefined behavior because `current` is uninitialized.

Here is a simplified and corrected version:

```
void loader(const char *word, const char *translation) {
    struct node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(*tempNode));
    struct node *current;

    if (tempNode == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        return;
    }
    tempNode->word = strdup(word);
    tempNode->translation = strdup(translation);
    tempNode->leftChild = tempNode->rightChild = NULL;

    /* If tree is empty */
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = tempNode;
        return;
    }
    for (current = root;;) {
       /* Goes to the left side of the tree */
        int cmp = strcmp(word, current->word);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "duplicate word: %s\n", word);
            free(tempNode->word);
            free(tempNode->translation);
            free(tempNode);
            return;
        }
        if (cmp < 0) {
            if (current->leftChild == NULL) {
                current->leftChild = tempNode;
                return;
            }
            current = current->leftChild;
        } else {
            if (current->rightChild == NULL) {
                current->rightChild = tempNode;
                return;
            }
            current = current->rightChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Your search function crashes on an empty dictionary because your test on `current == NULL` is done **after** dereferencing the pointer.  Incidentally, the tree is traversed in the wrong direction.

Here is a corrected version:

```
struct node *search(const char *word) {
    struct node *current = root;

    while (current) {
        int cmp = strcmp(word, current->word);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            printf("%s %s\n", current->word, current->translation);
            return current;
        }
        if (cmp < 0) {
            current = current->leftChild;
        } else {
            current = current->rightChild;
        }
    }
    printf("WORD DOESN'T EXIST: %s\n", word);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help,  search function is now working fine, but loader function is still not working. I give function parameters in the main like that:
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);
sscanf(str, "%s %s %s", option, word, translation);
Do u think this is the problem??

Comment: @ZéPedro: you should protect the destination arrays for `scanf` and `sscanf` `%s` and `%[` formats by inserting the maximum number of characters between the `%` and the `s` or `[`: `scanf("%999[^\n]%*c)`.  Also check the return value of `scanf` and `sscanf` to validate the number of parsed values. If the `sscanf` does not return 3, you cannot use `translation`, etc.